# Magento 1.9 performance - product with custom options

Tags: checkout, custom-options, performance, ce-1.9.0.1, indexing

**What's your opinion about Magento performance** - especially for checkout (indexing) when store is using products with custom options.

**Does it slow down the store a lot ?** I have one store (Magento 1.7.0.2) 200 simple/virtual products with custom options added (3-5 options for each products) and even I tried to use redis backend caching - I'm still getting 5-8s checkout comparing to 0.5-1s for fresh Magento 1.9 store with only straight simple products (doesn't contain custom options YET).

**Can I expect similar slow down of checkout if I add 3-5 custom options for each product on Magento 1.9.0.1 or it may be already tweak/fixed in 1.9?** I'm using VPS with SSD, database is a bit slow (but I'm using also CM Redis cache backen).

**Are simple products with custom options slower than setting configurable products > ? How both affect indexing/checkout ?**
Do you have any thoughts about that.

Thanks for help
Tomek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Magento 1.9 would drastically be better than 1.7 in terms of performance for your fully loaded catalog with custom options as such. However, it could be possible that the code for your checkout has customization to it that make it more inefficient and worsen performance.

You should do some profiling to find out the exact bottleneck for your checkout. New Relic is a great place to consider - :http://newrelic.com/ and plus it's free.

It could be the DB, inefficient code for custom options, a huge number of sales rules...anything. You will find out from new relic.